# pandas groupby two columns then retreive one group by key

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I can groupby a single column and then retrieve a selected group by key as follows:

Code:

```
np.random.seed(13)
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['apple', 'banana', 'orange'] * 3,
                   'col2': np.random.rand(9),
                   'col3': np.random.randint(0, 15, 9)})

print(df, '\n')

df_grouped = df.groupby(['col1'])

df_apple = df_grouped.get_group("apple")
print(df_apple, '\n')
```

Output:

```
    col1  col2  col3
0  apple 0.778    13
3  apple 0.966    11
6  apple 0.609     0
```

But when I try to groupby more than one column, no matter what I try, I get errors:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['apple', 'banana', 'orange'] * 3,
                    'col2': np.random.rand(9),
                    'col3': np.random.randint(0, 15, 9),
                    'col4': ['red', 'white', 'blue'] * 3})
print(df2, '\n')

# gb[["A", "B"]].get_group("foo")  <-- Found this on StackOverflow. Trying to use it as a guide.

df_grouped2 = df2.groupby(['col1', 'col4'])
df_apple2 = df_grouped2.get_group('apple')
print(df_apple2, '\n')
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mark/PycharmProjects/main/main.py", line 46, in <module>
    df_apple2 = df_grouped2.get_group('apple')
  File "C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 745, in get_group
    inds = self._get_index(name)
  File "C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 673, in _get_index
    return self._get_indices([name])[0]
  File "C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 646, in _get_indices
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: must supply a tuple to get_group with multiple grouping keys
```

I assume my syntax is incorrect but I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You need to pass all the grouping keys to extract the group: `df_grouped2.get_group(('apple', 'red'))`

Comment: @ShubhamSharma, Post as answer and I will accept.  Totally forgot that since I was grouping by two columns I needed to supply two keys.

Comment: Its fairly straightforward solution, so I'll pass on adding the answer but if you want to add answer please go ahead and I'll make sure to upvote you :-)